# Mantine clear checked value of other chips when one is selected

Tags: reactjs, mantine

I'm using the Mantine [chip group component](https://mantine.dev/core/chip/) to let users add some default values.  When 'Custom' is selected, it opens a drawer with a textbox to allow custom input. (See image below)

[image: Selection of chips for default values with a "Custom" chip at the very end]

I can't figure out though how to uncheck the previous four chips when Custom is selected though.

Here's my code:

```
  const Chips = chips.map((chip) => {
    return (
      <Chip
        classNames={classes}
        disabled={opened}
        key={chip.name}
        value={chip.value}
        defaultChecked={opened ? false : chip.defaultValue}
      >
        {chip.name}
      </Chip>
    )
  })

  return (
    <Chip.Group multiple value={textState} onChange={handleChange} spacing={30}>
      {chips.map((chip) => (
        <Chip
          classNames={classes}
          disabled={opened}
          key={chip.name}
          value={chip.value}
          defaultChecked={opened ? false : chip.defaultValue}
        >
          {chip.name}
        </Chip>
      ))}
      <Chip
        classNames={classes}
        checked={opened}
        onClick={() => {
          setOpen((o) => !o);
          //clear checked value of other chips
        }}
      >
        Custom
      </Chip>
    </Chip.Group>
  );
```

Comment: Looks like the first part of your code is never used? `const Chips = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve? If you would like to have an exclusive selection without the option to select multiple of the Chips at the same time, removing the `multiple` from the `<Chip.Group>` should do the job.

However, if this is not what you are trying to achieve and instead would like to allow the selection of multiple but make the custom chip exclusive you could do it like this:

```
const [chips, setChips] = useState(...add chips here...)
```

And your `onClick` function like this:

```
onClick={(event) => {
    setOpen(event.target.checked);
    //clear checked value of other chips
    if(event.target.checked){
        setChips([...chips.map(chip => {chip.value = false; return chip;})])
    }
}}
```

I hope this helps?

Answer (score -1):

If you set the `multiple` property of the chip group component to `multiple={false}`, users can only select one chip at a time and remove the previous chip selection.